# How do you change a git account on Xcode

Tags: xcode, git, github

```
"remote: Permission to (New Username)/BlockID.git denied to (Old Username)."
```

I am using a new account and whatever I do, Xcode takes an old account profile and tries to authenticate against the new account, which I should be using. Any idea on how to delete the old profile and use the new one? 
Preferences in Xcode appears to not use the old username, and none of my certificates and keychains contain the old profile.

Answer (score 0):

XCode takes this particular user information from your contact card from your Address Book

Comment: I believe I have nothing in my contact card that mentions the old username. :P